# Changing the CSS of Table Row OnClick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm Trying to change the background and text color of a table row on click using jQuery and CSS so that only one row may be selected at a time. However I cannot seem to get the CSS to change, even though the class is changing correctly from the jQuery function, so the jQuery appears to be working.

I am very confused why the CSS doesn't change when the class is changed (which I can see happening on the inspect element view on chrome).

Note that the table rows are being generated within a Django template page and the div classes are from Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row panel panel-default">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Pass #</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="member">
        {% for member in filter_list %}
          {% with member.pass_set.all|first as pass %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{member.id}}</td>
                <td>{{pass.active_id}}</td>
                <td>{{member.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{member.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{pass.member_type}}</td>
                <td>{{pass.season.is_current|yesno|capfirst}}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass(".selected");
    $(this).addClass(".selected");
});
```

```css
.member tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(41, 103, 182, 0.89);
    color: #FFF;
}
.selected tr{
    background-color: rgba(41, 103, 182, 0.89);
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I really thought this would be straight forward, but I have been stuck for a while. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Thanks for all the quick responses. I ended up taking advice from all three!

Final solution:

```
.member tr.selected {
    background-color: rgba(41, 103, 182, 0.89);
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```js
$("tbody tr").click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are adding the `selected` class to the `tr` element, so your CSS selector is incorrect. You may also want to make it more specific by prefixing it with `.member` too. Try this:

```
.member tr.selected {
    background-color: rgba(41, 103, 182, 0.89);
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Also, you may want to amend your jQuery so that only `tr` elements within the `tbody` can be selected - I doubt you want people to select the heading row:

```
$("tbody tr").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Note that there is no `.` prefix required for the `addClass()` or `removeClass()` methods.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRj8E/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.` in the `addClass` or `removeClass` methods. Likewise you don't need the `tr` in your CSS for the `.selected` class since you are adding it to a `tr` element...

http://jsfiddle.net/2E9T5/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7FbmV/

```
No need for dot:

$("tr").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use .selected, just selected, . is the class selector in css, similar to how # is the id selector.

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```